# jquery steps no funciona en angular 4

Tags: angular4, angular-directivas

los problemas que tiene jquery steps con angular 4 es que no me funciona para binding de un campo dentro de jquery steps. es decir
en el componente tengo una variable llamada

```
public borrar:string;
```

luego un metodo

```
loadInfo() {

this.borrar = "hola mundo"

}
```

en la vista que redenderiza tengo

```
<input type="button" (click)="loadInfo();" value="aqui">
{{ borrar }}
```

cuando doy click todo funciona normal. Muestra el valor de la variable.
pero si lo meto en donde se aplica jquery steps no funciona. no muestra nada ni error nada. ni valor de la variable.

el siguiente script es para aplicar jquery steps

```
var form = $("#example-form");
form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
});
```

al aplicar `form.children("div").steps` todas las variables que esten dentro del formulario con id "#example-form" dejan de funcionar, no se muestran para nada. llevo dias buscando como solucionar esto y no encuentro como resolverlo.

Comment: Porque usas Jquery con Angular 4? Puedes hacer todo nativo con Angular 4, y es lo mas recomedable

Comment: te dare un ejemplo. Hay varios plugins de javascript, ya hechos, con muchas validaciones y versiones que no sabria crearlos para angular 4. Por ejemplo ckeditor. Ckeditor tiene una gran cantidad de funcionalidades , hacer todo eso nativamente con angular 4 para un proyecto se convertiria en 2 proyectos, por un lado hacer todas las funcionalidades de un plugin y por otro adaptarlo. Te imaginas hacer todo ckeditor en angular4? otro plugin es clonar. el clone-ya.Y muchos mas. Te imaginas hacer todos los plugins nativamente como ckeditor? solo para un proyecto 25 plugins

Comment: seria interminable el proyecto. Podrias responderme esa pregunta? si te tocara plugins tan complejos como ckeditor digamos 30 plugins. Te pondrias hacerlos todos nativamente? que responderias a eso?

Comment: quedo atento a tu respuesta. Crear 30 plugins del nivel de complejidad de ckeditor en angular 4 nativamente. Lo harias?

Comment: Respondo a eso, que no has investigado en lo mas mínimo. Existe ckeditor ya exportado para Angular (v2-v4)

Comment: la pregunta fue, si harias el plugin para ckeditor para angular 4 porque mencionaste que porque no hacerlo nativamente.

Comment: una pregunta compa. Si quisiera usar plugins de javascript como fullcalendar, ckeditor porque ya tengo funcionalidades adaptadas a ese plugin en otros proyectos, no va a funcionar? tendria que buscarlos en angular 4 pero puede que las funcionalidades no sean las mismas respecto a su version. ?

Comment: te mencionare una funcionalidad que tengo en ckeditor pero que no esta en angular 4. kcfinder. tengo ya eso adaptado sin embargo la version y la compatibilidad de este plugin ckfinder no la veo en angular 4. Como resolverias eso? y hay otras mas. KCfinder ya es algo mas complejo que no encuentras en nagular 4. Hacerlo nativamente seria demasiado desgastante y larguisimo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La razón principal por la que eso no funciona es que el complemento jquery-steps elimina tu marcado html.

> Usar Jquery en Angular es una mala idea, pero si quieres que funcione,
>   puedo ofrecerte un poco de modificación para la biblioteca que talvez te
>   ayude.

### jquery.steps.js

```
function render(wizard, options, state) {
+    var contentWrapper = $('<{0} class=\"{1}\"></{0}>'.format(options.contentContainerTag, "content " + options.clearFixCssClass));
+    contentWrapper.append(wizard.children());
    // Create a content wrapper and copy HTML from the intial wizard structure
    var wrapperTemplate = "<{0} class=\"{1}\">{2}</{0}>",
        orientation = getValidEnumValue(stepsOrientation, options.stepsOrientation),
        verticalCssClass = (orientation === stepsOrientation.vertical) ? " vertical" : "",
-       //contentWrapper = $(wrapperTemplate.format(options.contentContainerTag, "content " + options.clearFixCssClass, wizard.html())),
```

### Información adicional:

**CKEditor** lo puedes obtener y usar en Angular. 
Puedes instalarlo de la siguiente forma y usarlo en tus componentes o modulo principal:

```
npm install ng2-ckeditor --save
```

Puedes leer su documentación y como usarlo, [aquí](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-ckeditor).

**KCFinder:**

> Desconozco su implementación para Angular, si existiese agradecería
>   quien lo dejara en comentarios.

Te puedo recomendar este FileManager, que busque pero al final no lo implemente:
[FileManager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rign/angular2-filemanager)

Comment: este funciono. Me parecio ver esta solucion en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40582639/use-jquery-steps-with-formgroup-in-angular2; Ya ahora empiezo a entender que angular 4 fue hecho para usarlo solo para angular 4 y nada mas. Usar js podria hacer que angular 4 y js plugins tengan incompatibilidades.

Comment: En el fondo Angular 4 es JS entonces se leva bastante bien, lo que trae problemas es JQuery muchas veces. Si, lo aprendí de SO, de esa respuesta.